# SqlCommand calling a SQL Server stored procedure times out

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures, sqlcommand

I've got a conversion utility that basically copies values from one table to another. It's worked great for a while, but I've run into a strange issue with one customer. They got through 1.5 million records with the utility but now it is completely halted.

When calling a stored procedure from VB.Net, it just hangs until the SqlCommand times out. Calling the same sproc from Management Studio executes instantly. My VB.Net code for the SqlCommand is below (`insertConn` is defined and opened earlier, `dr` is a SqlDataReader that has been populated in a previous step from completely different SqlConnection and SqlCommand instances):

```
Dim conn As New SqlConnection("connection string here")
Dim insertConn As New SqlConnection("connection string here")
Dim dr As SqlDataReader = Nothing
Dim readCommand As New SqlCommand("my query here", conn)
conn.Open()
insertConn.Open()
...
dr = readCommand.ExecuteReader()
...
While dr.Read()
    Using insertCommand = New SqlCommand("dmDocumentFieldInsert", insertConn)
        insertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocumentKey", dr("DocumentKey"))
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FieldId", "TITLE")
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FieldValue", dr("DocumentTitle"))
        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End While
```

I've tried restarting SQL Server to clear any locks, recompiling the sproc, increasing the SqlCommand and SqlConnection timeouts all to no avail.

I checked the data that is getting added to the parameters and it's valid data...if I manually call the sproc with the same data it works fine.

I originally was not using the `Using` block but changed that to see if there was some resource issue that wasn't getting disposed/closed. Memory usage of the utility hovers at just around 5MB, so there don't appear to be any memory issues.

Does anyone have suggestions on what to try next for a solution?

**EDIT** Added loop and init code per comment requests

**EDIT** I updated statistics and rebuilt the table indexes, no change.

**EDIT** There are three indexes on the table that the data is getting copied to (dmDocumentField). If I disable all three indexes then the sproc executes perfectly, albeit much slower than when the index is present. If I enable any one of them, then the utility gets through a couple hundred records at most then dies with the same timeout on the sproc. Deleting and recreating the index has no effect. Table structure and indexes are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dmDocumentField](
[FieldKey] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[DocumentKey] [char](36) NOT NULL,
[FieldId] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
[FieldValue] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dmDocumentField] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
[FieldKey] ASC,
[DocumentKey] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Indexes (besides the PK):

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [dmDocumentField_DocumentKey] ON [dbo].[dmDocumentField]
(
[DocumentKey] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [dmDocumentField_DocumentKey_IFieldId_IFieldValue] ON [dbo].[dmDocumentField]
(
[DocumentKey] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [FieldId],
[FieldValue]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: I should also mention, the utility is in VB.Net 4 and the SQL Server in question is SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard.

Comment: Anything unusual in the SQL profiler?

Comment: You could try using the data access methods in [Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648951.aspx).

Comment: Is this code called inside a loop? If yes, could you show also the loop code?

Comment: Just edited to show the loop, pretty standard stuff though.

Comment: does the code hang on a certain combination of parameter values? if so, how fast does it execute in SSMS for those same values?

Comment: Regarding the question about SQL Profiler info, it shows the sproc call as I expect it to: `exec dmDocumentFieldInsert @DocumentKey=N'my key',@FieldId=N'TITLE',@FieldValue=N'My Value'`, nothing unusual other than that though.

Comment: @JimMcKeon, It seems to be any parameter values. It runs in SSMS instantly for the exact same values.

Comment: If you use .AddWithValue then SQL Server generates a different execution plan for every distinct size of the parameter it is presented with (from my own testing). If you set the .Size when you create the SQL parameter then you get just one execution plan.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I will have to try that, maybe it is having an issue generating the execution plan...

Comment: @Kettch19 I hope you are working on a local copy of the customer's database, if at all possible. In which case, you can use SSMS to investigate what is going on.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I actually do have a local copy of their DB but the utility has no issues on the local copy, only on the one at the customer site. I have full access to their server though so I have SSMS available. I specified the parameter size and types for the `insertCommand` but it is still hanging and timing out.

Comment: @Kettch19 First I would verify that the statistics are up-to-date on the production server, then I would look to http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html .

Comment: @AndrewMorton Statistics are all updated. In addition I found some additional info on the indexes that I edited into my original post if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after fighting this some more I did the conversion by hand since this was a one-off issue for one particular customer. I still wish I knew why the SqlCommand was timing out but SSMS did not, but it's done at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I will try this:

```
... 
dr = readCommand.ExecuteReader() 
... 
insertCommand = New SqlCommand("dmDocumentFieldInsert", insertConn) 
insertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure 
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocumentKey", string.Empty)) 
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FieldId", "TITLE") 
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FieldValue", string.Empty)) 

Dim tr As SqlTransaction
tr = insertConn.BeginTransaction
insertCommand.Transaction = tr
While dr.Read() 
        insertCommand.Parameters("@DocumentKey").Value = dr("DocumentKey") 
        insertCommand.Parameters("@FieldValue").Value = dr("DocumentTitle")
        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() 
End While 

tr.Commit()
```

This probably will be less memory intensive (Create Command, Create Parameters repetead inside the loop) and with 1.5 million of record could be the difference.
**NOTE** I don't know the real datatype of @DocumentKey and @FieldValue, assumed to be strings, but if it is not the case then change the initial settings with an appropriate dummy value.

Comment: Good point, I didn't mention that all three parameters are strings. More specifically, DocumentKey is char(36), FieldId is varchar(10) and FieldValue is varchar(255).

Comment: Also, I originally had the code very close to your suggestion but in the heat of troubleshooting tried the other way. I just changed it back to your suggestion but no change in the result. :(

Comment: [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx) is very interesting. Are your columns of type VARCHAR instead of NVARCHAR? In the article there are strong advice on the problem created by the conversion from UNICODE.

Comment: Two of the columns are varchar, yes. The original columns that the values are pulled from also match in datatype so there is no conversion going on that I am aware of.

Comment: Last idea, use Transactions, just to see if it makes any difference

Comment: Unfortunately that made no difference either.

Comment: Now I really believe that the problem is not in the code. If we go back at the beginning you said that the problem exist only for a particular customer. So it's possible that we have some difference in the database structure (LOG, Collation, Table Indexes, Disk space or other dba stuff)

Comment: I agree. Latest info I have is that there are three indexes on the table that the data is getting copied to (dmDocumentField). If I disable all three indexes then the sproc executes perfectly, albeit much slower than when the index is present. If I enable any one of them, then the utility gets through a couple hundred records at most then dies with the same timeout on the sproc. Deleting and recreating the index has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Does your command perform operations on the same table(s) from which your DataReader selects? I had a similar situation in which I was doing something like executing a reader for

```
SELECT ID, Name FROM Table 1
```

and then my command that was timing out was looping through the DR records and doing something like

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Name = 'foo' WHERE ID = 1
```

When I changed my SELECT to use a DataTable for storage, rather than a DataReader, it worked immediately, as it did in SSMS.